# Print dates in jsp

Tags: jsp, date, html-table

I want to show the list of dates between two choosen dates (the user choose **dateA** and **dateB** and when he clicks on SUBMIT another jsp is open to **show the dates in a table** with another informations)
**The first ROW** is for labels: dates,driver,car,gas station
**The second row** is for informations;
so far i've done this :

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.GregorianCalendar"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="datepickeer" action="showdates.jsp" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td>Date début :</td> <td><input type = "date" name = "dateA"></td><tr>
<tr><td>Date Fin :</td> <td><input type = "date" name = "dateB"></td><tr>

<tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**showdates.jsp:**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.GregorianCalendar"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@ page import = "java.util.Date,java.text.SimpleDateFormat,java.text.ParseException"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>

<tr> 
<td> Dates </td>
<td> Driver</td>
<td> Car </td>
<td> Gas station </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>        
<% 
String dateA =request.getParameter("dateA");
String dateB =request.getParameter("dateB");

SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dateStart = null;
Date dateEnd = null;

dateStart = formater.parse(dateA);
dateEnd = formater.parse(dateB);

Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

c.setTime(dateStart);

List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

while (!c.getTime().after(dateEnd)) {
    dates.add(c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}

for (Date element: dates)
{
SimpleDateFormat newFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
out.println(newFormater.format( element));  
  } %> </td>
<td> Mr alaoui </td>
<td> 235647-A-23 </td>
<td> Marrakech,MOROCCO </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Help me please

Comment: What is your question? Why are you using scriptlets in JSPs, despite it being a bad practice for more than 10 years?

Comment: My question is how to insert Dates into HTML Table Cells,(in each row printed date from the loop :
    for (Date element: dates)
    {
    SimpleDateFormat newFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    out.println(newFormater.format( element));  
     }

Comment: use servlets and JSTL, to make your work easy. instead of mixing up everything in jsp. and avoid creating new `SimpleDateFormat` for each date.

Comment: <TR> is a row. <TD> is a cell.  Your loop doesn't print multiple rows, just multiple dates in one cell on one row.

Comment: @rembo : in manipulating date :idont know how to use anything else except SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @developerwjk: I want to have one date in cell, it means one date in each row

Comment: @NihadKH then go through [jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) & [servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: @rembo thank you but i need to print dates in a cell,not re-doing the entire calendar thing using servlet

Comment: @NihadKH check answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to have one date in cell, it means one date in each row

your code will write all dates in single `<td>` because your for loop is inside `<td>`, to get output as you stated in comment do like:

```
<table>
<tr> 
    <th> Dates </th>
    <th> Driver</th>
    <th> Car </th>
    <th> Gas station </th>
</tr>
start loop through your dates
   <tr>
     <td>print date</td>
     <td>print Driver</td>
     <td>print Car</td>
     <td>print Gas station</td>
   </tr>
end loop
</table>
```

---

But, better create a custom jsp tag function to do it easily and to keep all java codes inside it instead of jsp like:

create `dateDiff.tld` inside `${project_root}/(WebContent OR webapp)/WEB-INF/` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib>
 <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
 <short-name>DateDifference TLD</short-name>
 <jsp-version>2.1</jsp-version>
 <tag>
    <name>GetDatesStartEnd</name>
    <tag-class>com.jsp.tag.dateArrayListTagHandler.DateArrayListTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    <attribute>
       <name>start</name>
       <required>true</required>
       <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
      <type>java.util.Date</type>      
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
       <name>end</name>
       <required>true</required>
       <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
      <type>java.util.Date</type>      
    </attribute>    
    <attribute>
       <name>var</name>
       <required>true</required>       
      <type>java.lang.String</type>      
    </attribute>    
  </tag> 
</taglib>
```

and `DateArrayListTag` class like:

```
package com.jsp.tag.dateArrayListTagHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;

public class DateArrayListTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

    private Date start;
    private Date end;
    private String var;

    public void setVar(String var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    private List<Date> listDates;   

    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    public void setStart(Date start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
    public Date getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    public void setEnd(Date end) {
        this.end = end;
    }
    public List<Date> getListDates() {
        return listDates;
    }
    public void setListDates(List<Date> listDates) {
        this.listDates = listDates;
    }

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {  
        System.out.println("startDate: "+start);
        System.out.println("endDate: "+end);

        Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        listDates = new ArrayList<Date>();

        c.setTime(start);

        while (!c.getTime().after(end)) {
            listDates.add(c.getTime());
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }

        getJspContext().setAttribute(var, listDates);
    }

}
```

then, your showdates.jsp will be like:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/dateDiff.tld" prefix="dateDiff" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
th,td
{
padding:15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <fmt:parseDate value="${param.dateA}" var="parsedDateA" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    Date A:<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" type="DATE" value="${parsedDateA}" var="dateA" />${dateA}
    <fmt:parseDate value="${param.dateB}" var="parsedDateB" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    Date B:<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" type="DATE" value="${parsedDateB}" var="dateB" />${dateB}

    <dateDiff:GetDatesStartEnd end="${parsedDateB}" start="${parsedDateA}" var="resultDates"/>

<table>
<tr> 
    <th> Dates </th>
    <th> Driver</th>
    <th> Car </th>
    <th> Gas station </th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${resultDates}" var="curDt">    
<tr>
    <td>
        <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" type="DATE" value="${curDt}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        Mr alaoui
    </td>
    <td>
        235647-A-23
    </td>
    <td>
        Marrakech,MOROCCO
    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

[`jstl.x.x.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2) and `jsp-api.jar` file should be available in your project build-path.